# Find the Last Price that is different from the Current Price

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have sales transactions in a SQL Server table like this:

```
ItemNumber, TrxDate, UnitPrice
ABC, 1/1/2013, 10.00
ABC, 2/1/2013, 10.00
ABC, 3/1/2013, 13.00
ABC, 4/1/2013, 14.00
ABC, 5/1/2013, 14.00
XYZ, 1/1/2013, 18.00
XYZ, 2/1/2013, 18.00
XYZ, 3/1/2013, 20.00
XYZ, 4/1/2013, 20.00
XYZ, 5/1/2013, 20.00
```

I need a stored procedure to produce output that would look like this

```
ItemNumber, LastPrice, PriorPrice
ABC, 14.00, 13.00
XYZ, 20.00, 18.00
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: `LastPrice` and `PriorPrice` relative to what?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `lag()` function first to find when the price changes:

```
select ItemNumber,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then Price end) as LastPrice,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then Price end) as PriorPrice
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by ItemNumber order by TrxDate desc) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(Price) over (partition by ItemNumber order by TrxDate) as PrevPrice
            from t
           ) t
      where Price <> PrevPrice or PrevPrice is NULL
     ) t
group by ItemNumber;
```

Lag is only available starting with SQL Server 2012.

If you don't have `lag()`, you can do the same thing with a correlated subquery:

```
select ItemNumber,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then Price end) as LastPrice,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then Price end) as PriorPrice
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by ItemNumber order by TrxDate) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   (select top 1 t2.Price
                    from t t2
                    where t.ItemNumber = t2.ItemNumber and
                          t.TrxDate > t2.TrxDate
                    order by t2.TrxDate desc
                   ) as PrevPrice
            from t
           ) t
      where Price <> PrevPrice or PrevPrice is NULL
     ) t
group by ItemNumber;
```

Comment: There was one thing I had to change and that is where the text of the statement is "partition by ItemNumber order by TrxDate" I had to change to "partition by ItemNumber order by TrxDate desc".

Answer (score 0):

Assmunig SQL Server 2005+:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ItemNumber ORDER BY TrxDate DESC)
    FROM (  SELECT  ItemNumber,
                    MAX(TrxDate) TrxDate,
                    UnitPrice
            FROM YourTable
            GROUP BY ItemNumber,
                     UnitPrice) A
)
SELECT  ItemNumber,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN UnitPrice END) LastPrice,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN UnitPrice END) PriorPrice
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ItemNumber
```

Comment: . . This is quite clever and it *does* answer the question.  However, it wouldn't necessarily work if there were a prior prior price.  The problem is that the same price could be repeated multiple times -- at least in theory -- so the prior prior price could be the most recent price.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, you are right, didn't even think about that. Hopefully op would only need last and prior prices, otherwise my answer won't work